# Can't get Cordova Whitelist to work in phonegap app

Tags: php, android, ios, xml, cordova

I have tried adding the Cordova Whitelist plugin to my phonegap app that I am working on so my app can make calls to my site for data stored on a database. Here is my current config.xml file I have now for the app (Some data changed to protect privacy):

```
<widget id="com.test.testapp" version="1.0.0" versionCode="1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>My App</name>
    <description>
       A Testing App
    </description>
    <author email="myemail@test.com" href="test.com">
        The Author
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />

    <platform name="ios"/>
    <platform name="android"/>

    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />

<access origin="https://mywebsite.com/*" />

</widget>
```

The Config.xml is also in the same folder as the index.html file as well. Here is the header for the index.html for the app:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv = "Content-Security-Policy" content = "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css\cusom-css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
```

Every time I try and connect, I get this error:

```
    undefined Content Security Policy has been added: 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap: ws: 
https://ssl.gstatic.com;img-src 'self' data: content:;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-
inline' data: blob:;script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:;">
```

All I need the app to do is send and receive data from .php files hosted on my webpage, but no matter what I try, it will not connect. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to show the content from external website. But your content security policy is blocking xss

You should have the content policy as given below

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src 'self' http://10.0.2.2">`

or this one

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">`

You may also refere [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist#content-security-policy) to learn more about content policy given by cordova

**Note :**

From my personal experience. If you believe your website will not send any harmful content then, i would recommend you to remove the content policy header from your index.html. That will make your cordova app not block the xss.

Comment: I tried it before without the content policy header and it didn't work either, that's why I added it, I thought I needed it.

Comment: Have you tried removing the content policy entirely and allowed cross origin from your website ?

Comment: I have tried it with and without the content policy header, with and without cordova-plugin-whitelist, with and without the <access origin="https://mywebsite.com/*" />, no matter what combo I use, it will not connect to my site.

Comment: Also have you tried the above policy I given in my answers ?

Comment: Yup I tried everything you showed in your answer above, even removing the content policy header and it still won't connect.